# Flask App Error 500 When Using Vertex AI ChatModel

Tags: flask, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I am working on a Flask web application that includes a chatbot feature. I have integrated the Vertex AI (Artificial Intelligence) API into the app to use the ChatModel for the chatbot functionality. When I run the web application locally, everything works fine without any issues.

However, I encountered a problem when I deployed the app to Google Cloud using App Engine. After deployment, I started receiving "Error 500" (Internal Server Error) when trying to access the website.

To investigate the issue, I noticed that the problem occurs specifically when I include the following line in my code:

`from vertexai.preview.language_models import ChatModel, InputOutputTextPair, ChatSession`

If I remove or comment out this line, the website loaded perfectly fine without any errors but no longer a chatbot website

Here is the log:
[Log pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NaY8j.png)

1.Checked the "requirements.txt" file multiple times to ensure all the dependencies, including the Vertex AI-related libraries, were correctly listed.
2.Verified the presence of the required dependencies in my project by cross-referencing with the Python Docs Sample's GitHub repository.

I expected that after deploying my Flask web application to Google Cloud using App Engine, the chatbot functionality powered by the Vertex AI ChatModel would work seamlessly, just like it does when I test the application locally. I anticipated that users would be able to interact with the chatbot without encountering any "Error 500" or other unexpected issues.

Comment: Check your logs. What do you see in the logs?

Comment: Did you check the logs?

Comment: I still got a GET / HTTP/1.1 500 error, but I just found out that there is a chance that when I manually type it into the URL, I can get a 200 response. For example i  have to type "/home" into the url , there are 50% chances that it direct me to a page successfully same with other page

Comment: You can pull the container and run the image locally.